# Error in using str on a data.frame

Tags: r

I am getting an error when I trying to use the `str` function in R. 
Here is the data:

```
> dput(data1)
data1<- structure(list(Year = 1990:2010, Counts = c(1401L, 1290L, 1168L,1260L, 1252L, 1381L, 1330L, 1275L, 1235L, 1248L, 1237L, 1206L, 1175L, 1172L, 1055L, 1030L, 1002L, 987L, 915L, 806L, 868L)), .Names = c("Year", "Counts"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

I do not know why R is giving me the following error with `str` while `class` function is clearly saying that data1 is a `data.frame`.

```
> class(data1)
[1] "data.frame"
> str(data1)
Error in str(data1) : 
  unable to find a non-generic version of function "str"
```

I am using  R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30) for Windows.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
With a clean R session it worked. But why does this kind of problem occur? Is it possible to know this?

Comment: I am also using R 2.15 on Windows and it works for me. Did you try with a clean R session?

Comment: I do not get the error message.  I copied and pasted your data1 and did not use the dput statement.

Comment: You could see if `str` in the `utils` package is masked by a function of the same name in your workspace by typing `conflicts()` after you get the error and seeing if `str` comes up.

Comment: And perhaps `sessionInfo()` would help, too.

Comment: @ BenBarnes I entered `conflict()` and it did show `str` even in this clean session which does not repeat the _error_.

Comment: @Stat-R, that suggests that there is an object masking `str`. This could come from a package that you load automatically or a function you source at startup (perhaps in your Rprofile.site file?) Would you post the results of `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'll bite.

**Why does this kind of problem occur?**

Object (i.e. function, variable) masking is one of the most common sources of errors or bugs in R code. Why can this happen?

Well, there's a list of reserved words in R's parser located at `?Reserved`:

> The reserved words in R's parser are:
>
> `if` `else` `repeat` `while` `function` `for` `in` `next` `break`
>
> `TRUE` `FALSE` `NULL` `Inf` `NaN` `NA` `NA_integer_` `NA_real_` `NA_complex_`
>   `NA_character_`
>
> `...` and `..1`, `..2` etc, which are used to refer to arguments passed down
>   from an enclosing function.

That means you, the user, can't reassign the value of these names. But pretty much anything else (assuming its syntactically valid) is in bounds.

For example, `data` is actually a function in the **utils** package, which is why people generally recommend not naming your data frame `data`. You will have masked the *function* `data` and any code that depends on it will choke.

Honestly, I commonly use `df` for a data frame, even though that is a function that computes the distribution function for an F distribution. (I don't need the F distribution functions much. But I still shouldn't do that.)

A particularly devious example of this issue is the common joke among R users about setting:

```
T <- FALSE
F <- TRUE
```

Many people are lazy and use `T` and `F` for `TRUE` and `FALSE`, and now we see exactly why this is a really, *really* bad idea. (It's pretty likely that someone is going to assign some other value to `T` or `F`.)

Indeed, anytime you load a package you're likely to see a bunch of warnings, where R is telling you that by loading that package you've just masked a bunch of functions because they have common names.

**How can I know that this has happened?**

This is much easier. As Ben said in the comments, you identify this sort of thing using `conflicts()`.